# non-interactive password with createdb command

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a db using this command:

```
export PGPASSFILE="$HOME/pgpass/platform/.pgpass"

mkdir -p "$(dirname "$PGPASSFILE")"

echo "$db_host:5432:$db_name:platformadmin:$db_pwd" > "$PGPASSFILE"

chmod 600 "$PGPASSFILE"

createdb -h "$db_host" -p 5432 -U 'platformadmin' --no-password "$db_name"
```

but I am getting this error:

> createdb: could not connect to database template1: fe_sendauth: no
>   password supplied

if I remove the --no-password flag then it will prompt me for a password. I thought the PGPASSFILE would work??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used this instead:

```
PGPASSWORD="$admin_user_pwd" createdb -U admin_user -h "$db_host" -p 5432 --no-password -e "$db_name"
```

and it worked. No password file, just the command line.